# Need through guidance on Gradle script to execute soapui project xmls and generate report html

Tags: gradle, soapui

I have a gradle script to execute one one SOAPUI test suite. Currently the failed logs are coming in the same folder. I want to get all of the pass and failed 
logs to be created in separate folder. I want to have a index.html like report too to see the execution pass/fail reports. Does it create any testsuite.xml that stores the passed and failed data of each testcase like ANT?
I am not familiar with gradle. So I need a good gradle script that can help me out of this. My current gradle script is given below that executes only one test suite:

```groovy
class SoapUITask extends Exec {
    String soapUIExecutable = '/SOAPUIpath/SoapUI-5.1.2/bin/testrunner.sh'
    String soapUIArgs = ''
    public SoapUITask(){
        super()
        this.setExecutable(soapUIExecutable)
        //printReport=true

    }   
    public void setSoapUIArgs(String soapUIArgs) {
        this.args = "$soapUIArgs".trim().split(" ") as List
    }                                                                             
}
// execute SOAPUI
task executeSOAPUI(type: SoapUITask){
   // simply pass the project path as argument,
   // note that the extra " are needed
   soapUIArgs = '/path/of/SOAPUI project xml/src/PCDEMO-soapui-project.xml'
}
```

Comment: Your code should be placed together with your question, not as a comment. Please, edit your question and remove the comment. Also read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks ....I have done it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate and HTML report from [SOAPUI documentation](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/features/automation/testrunner/cli) you can use the follow parameters:

> -f - Specifies the root directory, where the runner will save test result files. If the specified directory does not exist, it will be
>   created.
>
> -F  Specifies the format of the exported reports. Usage: -F. Supported formats include PDF, XLS, HTML, RTF, CSV, TXT and XML. If the parameter is not specified, PDF is used.  To
>   export results in several formats, separate them with commas. For
>   example, -FPDF,XML,CSV.

**Note: As you can see on documentation the `-F` parameter only works for PRO version. If you use the free version when you try to use `-F` parameter you'll get the follow ouput:
    `org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException: Unrecognized option: -FPDF`**

So you can modify `task executeSOAPUI` to add `-f location` and `-FHTML` as follows:

```java
// execute SOAPUI
task executeSOAPUI(type: SoapUITask){
   // simply pass the project path as argument,
   // note that the extra " are needed
   soapUIArgs = '-f "path/of/outputReports" -FHTML "/path/of/SOAPUI project xml/src/PCDEMO-soapui-project.xml"'
}
```

If instead you are expecting a Junit Html style report you can try with the follow parameter (which is also only available in PRO version):

> -R  - Specifies the type of the report data.
>
> Usage: -R. Report type can be one of the following:
>
> Project Report - Generates a report in the format that is specified by the -F argument. The runner will save the report files to the directory that the -f argument specifies. Depending on the -A argument value, the files can be
>   organized into subdirectories.
>
> TestSuite Report - As above, but for TestSuites.
>
> TestCase Report - As above, but for TestCases.
>
> JUnit-Style HTML Report - Generates a report as JUnit-style HTML files. See JUnit-Style HTML Reports. When this value is used, the runner ignores the -F and -A arguments.
>
> Data Export - Generates XML files with report data. See Data Export.  When you use this argument, -F must be XML or must not be specified.
>
> Use the -f argument to specify the directory, where the runner will
>   save generated report files.

Using this your `task` could be:

```java
// execute SOAPUI
task executeSOAPUI(type: SoapUITask){
   // simply pass the project path as argument,
   // note that the extra " are needed
   soapUIArgs = '-f "path/of/outputReports" -R"JUnit-Style HTML Report" "/path/of/SOAPUI project xml/src/PCDEMO-soapui-project.xml"'
}
```

**Disclaimer: I don't have a PRO version so I can't test any of the options I give in the answer.**

Comment: As suggested I have run the following code:

           task executeSOAPUI(type: SoapUITask){
      // simply pass the project path as argument,
       // note that the extra " are needed
              soapUIArgs = '-f "/path/of/SOAPUI/build/soapui-reports-html" -j "/path/of/SOAPUI project xml/src/project.xml"'

               }

But it encontered with following error:

            java.lang.Exception: Failed to load SoapUI project file        ["/path/of/SOAPUI project xml/src/project.xml"]

Any idea?

Comment: @user2530711 you've a PRO version? and is your `/path/of/SOAPUI project xml/src/project.xml` project path? can you try first directly run from command line to check if it works correctly before to execute it from gradle? `/SOAPUIpath/SoapUI-5.1.2/bin/testrunner.sh -f "/path/of/SOAPUI/build/soapui-reports-html" -j "/path/of/SOAPUI project xml/src/project.xml"`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am able to see the failed log txt files in a specific folder though it doesnot save OK.txt files which are passed. The index.html had not been created. After running the gradle build I am getting following error:Process 'command /SOAPUIpath/SoapUI-5.1.2/bin/testrunner.sh' finished with non-zero exit value 255

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer as a separate POST because I think that it's a good option for who doesn't have a PRO version, and good enough to have their space.

So the possible alternative is to generate the Junit Xml report files and then generate the Html using the Xml report and Xslt transformation.

To generate the Junit Xml report you can use the `-j` parameter, and also `-f` to specify the folder.

And then you can create a gradle task to perform the XSLT transformation (my solution is based on [this solution on github](https://gist.github.com/cburgmer/2295010)).

So your `build.gradle` could be:

```java
repositories {       
     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}

configurations { 
  antClasspath 
} 
// dependency for XMLResultAggregator task
dependencies { 
  antClasspath 'org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.8.2' 
} 


class SoapUITask extends Exec {
    String soapUIExecutable = '/SOAPUIpath/SoapUI-5.1.2/bin/testrunner.sh'
    String soapUIArgs = ''

    public SoapUITask(){
        super()
        this.setExecutable(soapUIExecutable)
    }

    public void setSoapUIArgs(String soapUIArgs) {
        this.args = "$soapUIArgs".trim().split(" ") as List
    }
}

// execute SOAPUI
task executeSOAPUI(type: SoapUITask){

    def reportPath = 'path/of/outputReports'

    soapUIArgs = '-f "' + reportPath + '" -j "/path/of/SOAPUI project xml/src/PCDEMO-soapui-project.xml"'

    // perform the xslt
    doLast {
        soapuiXmlToHtml(reportPath)
    }

}

// task to perform the XSLT
def soapuiXmlToHtml(resultsDir) {
    def targetDir = new File(resultsDir, 'html')

    ant.taskdef(
        name: 'junitreport',
        classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLResultAggregator',
        classpath: configurations.antClasspath.asPath
    )

    ant.junitreport(todir: resultsDir) {
        fileset(dir: resultsDir, includes: 'TEST-*.xml')
        report(todir: targetDir, format: "frames")
    }
}
```

Then you can invoke `gradle executeSOAPUI` and your JUnit Html report will be generated on `path/of/outputReports/html/` folder.

Hope it helps,