# I want to run multiple SOAPUI project xmls in Gradle script

Tags: gradle, soapui

I want to run multiple soapui projects in Gradle script. The SOAPUI project files are kept is following location:
d:/soapui/projects/path/a.xml, b.xml etc

Will be there any Gradle script that it will enter into the above mentioned location and execute the each project one by one using testrunner.bat

Comment: Do not aware of graddle. However, you should be able to provide absolute soapui project xml file path to testrunner script. Is not it working like?

Comment: There is a soapui gradle plugin: https://github.com/byte-shifter-ltd/soapui-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 1):

As @RaGe comments you can use the [*gradle SOAPUI plugin*](https://github.com/byte-shifter-ltd/soapui-gradle-plugin). However if you're looking for a more custom way you can proceed as follows.

You can generate a task on *Gradle* to execute *testrunner* to run your *SOAPUI* projects. Then you can create dynamically one task for each project you've in a directory path, and using `.depends` you can make that all these dynamic generated tasks are called when you call the specific task.

Your *build.gradle* could be something like:

```java
// task to execute testrunner
class SoapUITask extends Exec {
    String soapUIExecutable = '/SOAPUI_HOME/bin/testrunner.bat' 
    String soapUIArgs = ''

    public SoapUITask(){
        super()
        this.setExecutable(soapUIExecutable)
    }

    public void setSoapUIArgs(String soapUIArgs) {
        this.args = "$soapUIArgs".trim().split(" ") as List
    }
}

// empty task wich has depends to execute the
// ohter tasks
task executeSOAPUI(){
}   

// get the path where are your projects
def projectsDir = new File(project.properties['soapuiProjectsPath'])

// create tasks dynamically for each project file
projectsDir.eachFile{ file ->
    if(file.name.contains('.xml')){
        // create the tasks
        task "executeSOAPUI${file.name}"(type: SoapUITask){
            println "execute project ${file.name}"
            soapUIArgs = ' "' +  file.getAbsolutePath() +'"'
        }

        // make the depends to avoid invoke each task one by one
        executeSOAPUI.dependsOn "executeSOAPUI${file.name}"
    }   
}
```

To invoke this you can do it using the follow command:

`gradle executeSOAPUI -PsoapuiProjectsPath=d:/soapui/projects/path/`

Note that `-P` is used to pass the parameter for projects dir.

Recently I wrote an answer on how to write *gradle task* to run *SOAPUI* which can be also util, if you want check more [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35774134/1218618).

Hope this helps,