# How to run multiple projects at a single launch?

Tags: soap, soapui

I have 4 projects, which are depended each other,I am suppose to run 4 projects one by one.

Is there any way to run as single package?

Comment: did you mean run all 4 project with the same `testRunner` call in sequential order since its has dependencies? `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you're running the *SOAPUI* project using *testRunner*. Looking at [*testRunner* documentation](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/features/automation/testrunner/cli#_ga=1.149487606.1119583330.1351276049) you can see that it's only possible to pass one project to the call.

However if you're using some automation build tool like *gradle* you can create and approach creating a custom task to for example make various calls to *testRunner* passing your projects to execute all sequentially, for more details take a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35892945/1218618).

If you're not using any automation tool or you don't know how to implement it then as a possible workaround you can simply can create a *CLI script* to do so. For example supposing that you've the `SOAPUI_HOME/bin` in your classpath on Windows you can create **myTestRunner.bat** with the follow content:

```
call testrunner "path/to/your/project1.xml"
call testrunner "path/to/your/project2.xml"
call testrunner "path/to/your/project3.xml"
...
```

Hope it helps,