# Need Gradle code to generate JUnit index.html report after SOAPUI test execution

Tags: gradle, soapui

I had an ANT script that executes SOAPUI reports and generates TEST-*.xmls. The next ANT script code generates html report and find below the ANT code for JUNIT report:

```
 <junitreport todir="${basedir}/build/soapui-reports-html">
  <fileset dir="/opt/jenkins/workspace/soapui-reports">
   <include name="**\TEST-*.xml" />
  </fileset>
 <report format="frames" styledir="${basedir}/styledir"            
   todir="${basedir}/build/soapui-reports-html">
  <param name="current-date" expression="${TODAY}"/>
   <param name="element-name" expression="${element.name}"/>
  </report>
</junitreport>
```

I am currently moving the whole SOAPUI test execution in Gradle from ANT and am able to get the TEST-*.xml for each project. It would be great help if there is any code to get the JUNIT report i.e. index.html using same gradle script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to create JUNIT index.html report in Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193589/want-to-create-junit-index-html-report-in-gradle)

Comment: You're asking again the same question? please check the response http://stackoverflow.com/a/35774134/1218618

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/byte-shifter-ltd/soapui-gradle-plugin) gradle plugin to configure your soapUI gradle integration. And then set `junitReport` task properties to true as mentioned , to get Junit type report